# In one-to-many relationship tables, get only those rows from table A that have multiple corresponding rows in table B

Tags: sql, join, one-to-many

I have two tables with *one-to-many* relations.
**A** and **B**.

**A** has two attributes: `pkA` and `name`
**B** has three attributes: `pkB`, `name` and `pkA`, where `pkA` stores the `pkA` of table **A**.

Now I want to write a query that will give me only those names of the table **A** that have more than one corresponding entry in table **B**.

---

*Example*-

**A**

```
a1     name1
a2     name2
a3     name3
```

**B**

```
b1    name1    a1
b2    name2    a1
b3    name3    a3
```

The query must return only a1, name1 because only a1 has multiple references in table **B**.

Comment: You could `COUNT` the number of `pkB` rows and use that in a `HAVING` clause. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select pkA
from b
group by pkA
having count(*) > 1;
```